# Sort a list of object with 2 props are String and Integer, sort this list by alphabetical and if the String is the same, sort by DESC Integer

Tags: java, sorting

```
class Car {
    private String maker;
    private int rate;
}


   @Override
public void f3(List<Car> t) {
    Collections.sort(t, (Car c1, Car c2) -> {
    if(c1.getMaker().compareTo(c1.getMaker()) > 0)
        return 1;
    else if(c1.getMaker().compareTo(c1.getMaker()) < 0 )
        return -1;
    else{
        if(c1.getRate() > c2.getRate())
            return -1;
        else if(c1.getRate() == c2.getRate())
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
        
    });
}
```

For Example:
A list before sort:
(C,1) (B,2) (B,3) (A,4)
after sort
(A,4) (B,3) (B,2) (C,1)

I used the code like the above but it's just sort by alphabetical OR by descending Integer.
Please help me!
Thanks!

Comment: You compare c1 with c1 instead of c2. ;)

Comment: :> my fault, thanks very much

Comment: some error really simple but somtime i miss it :> my bad

Answer (score 2):

To remove the error, comparing `c1.getMaker()` with itself:

```
Collections.sort(t, Comparator.comparing(Car::getMaker)
    .thenComparingInt(c -> -c.getRate()));
```

There is also the possibility to use [`reverse/reverseOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), but more unreadable IMHO.

`Car::getMaker` is the same as `c -> c.getMaker`.

---

***Using reversed:*** (not so comprehensible)

I think it must be done first reversing the makers, natural order of rates, and then reversing all.

```
Collections.sort(t, Comparator.comparing(Car::getMaker) // A B B C
    .reversed()                                         // C B B A
    .thenComparingInt(Car::getRate)                     // C1 B3 B4 A4
    .reversed());                                       // A4 B4 B3 C1
```

Or

```
Comparator<Car> rateReverse = Comparator.comparingInt(Car::getRate).reversed();
Collections.sort(t, Comparator.comparing(Car::getMaker) // A B B C
    .thenComparingInt(rateReverse);                     // A4 B4 B3 C1
```

Note that Comparator.comparing/comparingInt /thenComparing/... as parameter either have a Comparator again (`rateReverse`), or a key extractor (`Car::getMaker`) with which to compare.

Maybe some reader knows a better way.

Comment: thanks very much, i will try it and preview later